# Dynamic app.get URL Switch Case With Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, switch-statement

I am attempting to simplify some web server code (Node.js and Express) and I would like to use only one app.get statement for simplicity. I tried this:

```
app.get(url, function(req, res){
    switch(url){
        case "/":
            res.sendfile('index.html');
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            console.log("Client requested /");
            break;
        case "/profile":
            res.sendfile('profile.html');
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            console.log("Client requested /profile");
            break;
        default:
            res.sendfile('404.html');
            res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            console.log("Client requested page not found - 404 error");
    }
});
```

But it's throwing a "reference error: url is not defined" error. Do I really need to code each potentially requested URL as a string literal for the first parameter and have multiple app.get statements or is there a way to use a switch case, or something comparable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a map based lookup to map a url and a resource. Package this in a middleware with [`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/api#app.use).

```
app.use(function(req, res){
    routes = {
      '/': 'index.html',
      '/profile': 'profile.html'
    };

    var url = req.url;

    if (routes[url] !== undefined) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.sendfile(route[url]);
        console.log("Client requested", url);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.sendfile('404.html');
        console.log("Client requested page not found - 404 error");
    }
});
```

Comment: When I tried your method, the code appeared to being working in that when I requested a specific page it would display the correct console.log message, but it wouldn't load the page and I got a Windows "Firewall blocked a requested from V8 Engine, etc." error

Comment: @Eric Disable it or add an exception for node.